# CPack empty CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, packaging, cpack

I am really struggling to get CPack to act the way I am imagining it should. I have a small example setup below that I have been trying to get work before applying it to a much larger project. Essentially I am trying to use fixup_bundle to collect all dependencies and copy them to the packaging directory to be combined into an installer (and zip).

main.cpp:

```
int main(unsigned int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Multimedia Widgets AxContainer OpenGL)

add_executable(TEST main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TEST
    Qt5::AxContainer
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Multimedia
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::OpenGL
    )

install(
    TARGETS TEST
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    COMPONENT Runtime
    )

install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_PACKAGING_PREFIX=${CPACK_PACKAGING_PREFIX}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=${CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH=${CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_TEMPORARY_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME=${CPACK_TEMPORARY_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\")")
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CPACK_TEMPORARY_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=${CPACK_TEMPORARY_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\")")


install(CODE "
   include(BundleUtilities)
   fixup_bundle(\"${CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY}/TEST${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}\"   \"\"   \"${DIRS}\")
   " COMPONENT Runtime)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP" "NSIS")

include(CPack)
```

And the output is always a bunch of empty variables:

```
CPACK_PACKAGING_PREFIX=
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Program Files (x86)/Project
CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX=
CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX=
CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=
CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH=
CPACK_TEMPORARY_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME=
CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=
CPACK_TEMPORARY_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:861 (message):
  error: fixup_bundle: not a valid bundle, app: /TEST.exe
```

Obviously it won't find the right executable. I am expecting CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY to be something like:

${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_CPack_Packages/${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}/${CPACK_GENERATOR}/${CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME}

**Update 2016-06-23**

Thanks to @Tsyvarev for helping identify problem + solution. The issue is pre-mature expansion of the variables inside the install commands. CMake will do a first level expansion for any ${} variables in the text lines. Escaping the variable as \${} avoids this expansion and will later be expanded correctly by CPack.

Even with the above, all of the variables are still empty except for one. Fortunately it is the right one:

```
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}\")")
```

results in:

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/User/Documents/dev/build-test_deploy-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Default/_CPack_Packages/win32/ZIP/Project-0.1.1-win32
```

Now the bundling will work as such:

```
install(CODE "
   include(BundleUtilities)
   fixup_bundle(\"\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/TEST${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}\"   \"\"   \"\")
   " COMPONENT Runtime)
```

Maybe one more important note, since the fixup_bundle is using a set of fixed strings you are going to have to have a pretty ridge install structure. Essentially the above will only work for monolithic installs:

```
set(CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL on)
```

I'd be interested in a better solution than the above, but I can work with this.

Comment: `CPACK_*` variables are defined by `include(CPack)` call, they are not accessible before it. While you use `install(CODE)` command for output at *install* stage, variable's substitution is performed immediately, on *configure* stage, when `CPACK_` variables are not defined.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a correct way to see these variables during cpack execution? Because this will be a problem even for the fixup_bundle call which needs to be executed on the delivered exe. I have tried running fixup_bundle on just the exe name or cake install prefix + exe name, and fixup_bundle never finds it. This led me to start evaluating how to build the path to the right exe name.

Comment: Just place all CPack-dependent code, like `fixup_bundle()` call, **after** `include(CPack)`.

Comment: I tried this, and a few more variables are defined after include(CPack), but not much:

`CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME=Project-0.1.1-Source`
`CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Program Files (x86)/Project`
`CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY=Project 0.1.1`

And nothing for CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY, and no mention of _CPack_Packages.

Comment: Hm, looks like *CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY* variable is magic that its default value comes only at *install* stage. For refer to such variables in `install(CODE)` commands, you need to escape their dereference: `\${CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY}`.

Comment: If you haven't already, perhaps have a look at the implementation of `DeployQt4.cmake` which is in the `share/cmake-x.y/Modules` directory of your CMake install. That file contains various functions which largely seem to be doing something similar to what you are trying to do. While DeployQt4 won't work for Qt5 apps, the implementation details it contains may help guide you to a working solution. You may also want to consider taking a look at the [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) tool that comes with Qt itself.

Comment: You nailed it @Tsyvarev thanks! I recall trying this but I must not have had my print statements correct. Strange enough, I really need the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable, and all the others are still blank! It is set correctly before the include(CPack) `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/User/Documents/dev//build-test_deploy-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Default/_CPack_Packages/win32/ZIP/Project-0.1.1-win32`. I will add updates to the question text, but feel free to make an answer.

Comment: @CraigScott, thanks I actually use the windeployqt also, but I am/was having trouble linking this to a proper install cmake command. Now the fixup_bundle is collecting dependencies correctly across installers. I will be using the windeployqt to collect the plugin and platform folders alongside the bundling.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Bad advice, because `INCLUDE(CPack)` must be the last call.

Comment: @JensA.Koch: As far as I know, placing `include(CPack)` at the end is not a *requirement*, but a **recommendation**, because things becomes easier. So, in some case you may violate the recommendation. Of course you need to be very careful while doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way for use CPack variables, defined at **install time**, with `install(CODE)` command:

```
install(CODE " 
    include(CPack)
    MESSAGE(\"CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=\${CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY}\")
")
```

Main points here:

1. Expansion of the variable should be escaped: `\${...}`. Otherwise, variable is expanded immediately on *configure* stage, when it has not defined yet.
2. *Install* code still needs to `include(CPack)` for make CPack variable's available.

Answer (score 0):

For those who hopelessly was trying to apply all recipes in internet (like me) I have one more to get this directory which worked for me:

```
install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"DESTDIR=\$ENV{DESTDIR}\")")
```